# Keyboard lag on iPhone SE

Tags: keyboard, ssh

When I use an app called Termius on iOS to SSH into my different machines, I am starting to get serious keyboard lag lately. I’ve already tried resetting the dictionary and I’ve restarted my phone.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?

I am running iOS 12.2.

Comment: Is this happening only when using the Terminus app or across all apps? What is the version of iOS running on your iPhone?

Comment: this is only when using the termius app, and im currently running iOS 12.2

Answer (score 1):

Since you are facing the issue only with a single app, it most likely is a bug with the app, not with the iOS software or the hardware.

The resolution step would be to report the same to the developer of the app. The contract information can be found on the App Store page of the app. You can also try by running the app on other iOS devices if you have access to any.

Comment: ok, yes it seems to work just fine from the other iOS i have access to. so ill go and file a bug report. hey man thanks for your help.!